# Angular2/Javascript table export to Excel

Tags: javascript, excel, angular

Hi guys we seem to have trouble with the format of the exported excel file here is our code:

```
import { Component,ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `<input type="button" (click)="tableToExcel('testTable', 'W3C Example Table')" value="Export to Excel">
            <table id="testTable" rules="groups" frame="hsides" border="2">
            <tr>
                <th>111111</th>
                <th>222222</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>333334</td>
                <td>444443x</td>
            </tr>
            </table>
             `
})

export class AppComponent{

    tableToExcel(table, name){
    let uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
        , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
        , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(decodeURI(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
        , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
            if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
            var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
            window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
        }
    }
```

Here is the screenshot of the output:
[image: Excel File]

as you can see there certain html elements included in the parsing, how do I format it correctly?

Comment: Have you got the solution?

Answer (score 1):

We figured it out might as well answer this if someone needs a reference we just changed the "decodeURI" to "decodeURIComponent" and the format turned out fine.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use ExcellentExport.js https://github.com/jmaister/excellentexport to convert the table to Excel.

Note: I am the developer of the library.